# Azure MVC Continous Integration Vs Publishing - missing Owin dll

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, continuous-integration

I have a strange issue.

When I publish my MVC site to Azure it works.
When I hook it up to deploy using continuous integration on check-in I get a missing dll:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

[image]

I can't work out what is going on as the code base is always the same!

All, after reading a couple of comments I have uploaded the following images. All my Owin references are coming from Nuget but it looks like I have a few different version numbers of Own references. I don't know why this would be as the web project.

I have searched my project for the word Owin and found there are very few references and, as you can see in this image, there are 3 different version numbers for various DLLs that are related to Owin:

[image]

Also, here are all the references to Owin in my Visual Studio Online build log:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Maybe someone can comment on why there are varying version?

thanks
Russ

Comment: How are you referencing the Owin dll in your source? Gac, Nuget package , folder structure reference?

Comment: Hi @user92454. Thanks for the reply. I am using Nuget. I have added a pic of my packages file.

Comment: I have had a similar problem but in my source, I was referencing the dlls using folder structure reference and in my build machine it was pulling the reference from GAC which had older version. You can look at the detailed build logs and search for Microsoft.Owin.dll - it would tell where it is referencing it from. If you are using Nuget, I suspect it might be a different issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out in the build logs. Although owin in got added through nuget so I think I have another issue. I'll up vote when I find the issue